# MongoDB Database schema for ecommerce

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, e-commerce

Im currently building a multi User ecommerce app, (like shopify but for another sector). Im using nodejs with mongoDB. What is the best practice to store the orders?

Im currently have this schema:

```
UserModel{
username,
password,
ownsStore:}

StoreModel{storeID,
owner:,
products:[productarray],
categories:[],
orders:[array with all OrderModel{
orderid:
oderitems}]}
```

Will the Orders array in the store get to big?
Is it better Practice to put the Orders in a own colloction and assign them to the stores by using find and only saving the ObjectId in the order array of the store?

Answer (score 4):

This schema will create you problems when the data will get bigger. Instead of doing this you should create different object for each order and map them with any unique ID of user.

The problem in this will come when you would like to sort various orders then you have to either use aggregation query which will take more time as compared to normal query or you will have to manually sort orders by using forEach or map functions.

Secondly you will also face problems while updating document if nested arrays comes into play because mongoDB does not provide support for deeply nested arrays so you would have to set again and again the value of array by manually updating array.

If you make different objects then all those things would get easier and faster to do.
I have worked on ecommerce project and have experienced the issues, so I later changed them to different object for each order.

So define a different schema for orders and add a unique ID of user in each order, so that the mapping becomes easy